# Convert Array of Char to String?

Tags: delphi

How do I convert an array of char to a string?

I have a normal array of characters  and I want to convert its values to string.
How can I do this?

**Edit:** *Originally this question asked about "array of string to string",  but the OP accepted an answer that said "array of char, to string".*

Comment: Do you simply want to concatenate them, or something more involved?

Comment: Well currently I have an array for e.g with "apple, pear, oranges" as values and want to convert that to a string.

Comment: You still haven't really explained what you want. Do you want them comma-separated, or just mashed together, or something else?

Comment: So you want them space-separated?

Comment: Nope, Just converted to a string. Okay, lets say my current array has a value of "Hello, my name is John", how do I convert that to string?

Comment: That is already a single string. Do you perhaps mean an `array of char`?

Comment: What is the data type of your array?

Comment: That's a completely different question. I suspect this is going nowhere until you present some code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Edited question to fit accepted answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems that perhaps you have text in an `array of char`. If so then you can do this:

```
function ArrayToString(const a: array of Char): string;
begin
  if Length(a)>0 then
    SetString(Result, PChar(@a[0]), Length(a))
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

On the other hand, maybe you're asking a completely different question.

Comment: @Marcelo Thanks for the edit. I'm embarrassed by my shoddy spelling.

Comment: No worries; it's a very common typo. At least you didn't write "loosing"; that one makes me shudder.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo and David. I figured out what I wanted to do (was my own stupidity) Thanks again :)

Comment: And what was it that you wanted to do?

Comment: John, don't call "array of Char", an "array of string".  Pretty big difference.

Comment: Easier to just assign the array of char to the string. `s := myCharArray;`

Answer (score 1):

```
function ArrayToString(const Data: array of string): string;
var
  SL: TStringList;
  S: string;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for S in Data do
      SL.Add(S);
    Result := SL.Text;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This is how I understand what you are asking. It could be that David's solution is what you want, however. You decide.

Comment: The OP was terribly confused, and I think that you probably guessed that.  If the real question was, "array of string", to a string, this would work.

Comment: I thought the real question was array of string. I see that was edited and now it is array of char. Then SetString is the solution, indeed.

Comment: Actually, a TStringBuilder might have been better. But probably only marginally. I never profiled the efficiency of Delphi's TStringBuilder.